# Create and edit M:N binding in large tables in GUI/Web app?

Tags: gui-design, web, hyperlinks, data-tables, multi-column

How to enable end-user to create M:N bindings for large multi-column tables?
In our case there are tables up to thousands items large. Each table has number of columns.

For example Cars (Manufacturer, model, engine, year, ...) and Spare part (Name, part number, store number, height, diameter)

How to enable field expert to create and manage such catalog: What car (X) can use spare part (Y). When creating the binding our exert needs not only to see a name of car/spare part, but also number of other columns.

Car/spare parts are only an example. Please do not specialize the solution for this case only.

Basic use cases:

- We have tables without bindings and expert want to create new bindings.
- Tables and bindings exists, expert wants to enter new spare part and then immediately add to cars.
- Expert adds now car and want it to add similar parts like similar cars have.
- Expert adds new type of a part and what to add it to cars as similar part have. Exact list of cars is decided by his knowledge during data edit.
- Expert got information on certain part (cars where it can be used) and wants to check and add missing binding.
- Expert got information about possible invalid bindings, want to check them and delete if they exists.

Comment: This is written in quite a domain specific way. What is a 'binding'?

Comment: Binding is the information that for example part X can be used in car Y. So it's  information how assemble out desired "tree" from rows from different tables.